# Android Loopj's Async JsonObject reponse is cast to Objectid failed

Tags: java, android, json, rest, loopj

I'm relatively new in Android & Restful API programming, so I might be making some stupid mistakes. However I am facing this from my response JsonObject:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"login\" at path \"_id\" for model \"User\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"login\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"login","path":"_id"}

I have tested my Rest API on Postman and everything returns just fine. The Restful API is written in Node.js and Express.

The Rest API is suppose to return a status, userid, and message to let the app know if the user logged in using the right username and password. The login works fine and it returns me a 200 which allows the app to login and keep it logged in using a session. However, I can't get anything from the response JsonObject to get the userid for my next step in displaying user information.

(Target Android API 23)

Code:

Restful.Java

```
public class RestClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/";
    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl){
        Log.d("URL: ", BASE_URL+relativeUrl);
        return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.Java (Only the login part)

```
public void checkLoginDB(final RequestParams params, final String username){
        prgDialog.show();     

        RestClient.post("user/login", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                Log.d("StatusCode: ", "Code "+ statusCode);
                try {
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        session.createLoginSession(username);
                        Log.d("Log: ", "what " + response);
                        navigatetoHomeActivity();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("StatusCode: ", "Code "+ statusCode);
                prgDialog.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Restful API's Server.js

```
  router.post('/user/login', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    if(username.length > 0 && password.length > 3){
      User.findOne({username: username, password: password}, function(err, user){
        if(err)
          res.json({statusCode: 0, message: "login error: " + err});
        if(!user)
          res.json({statusCode: 0, message: "Not Found"});

        res.json({statusCode: 200, userid: user._id, message: "Login Sucessful"});
      })
    } else {
      res.json({statusCode: 0, message: "Invalid Fields"});
    }
  });

  app.use('/api', router)
```

User.js (Defined schema)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  agentID: Number,
  email: String,
  phone: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to Login the user and want user details in return use post() method.
in your code the second method is not post, so change `client.get()` to `client.post()`

like this `public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }`

Comment: I tried both get and post. nothing changed, still the same error. But you are right about that mistake, I changed it to post now, however that doesn't get rid of the error...EDIT: I updated the code in the question to reflect that

Comment: Which values you passed to the params?

Comment: this is my own code and its work for me try it out. `public void getLogin(String username,String password,JsonHttpResponseHandler handler){

            HashMap<String,String> params= new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email",username.toString());
            params.put("password",password.toString());
            RequestParams param = new RequestParams(params);

            String url = getApiUrl("/login");
            client.post(url,param,handler);
}`

Comment: OMG...I just got a response...it was because the emulator was bugged! The only reason I hate android...YOUR ANSWER was CORRECT! All because I overlooked the auto fill when I was typing get and post! EDIT: I have to restart the emulator everytime I test a new build..apparently it bugs if i dont